# Как соединить имя пути и файла?

Tags: c++, winapi

Нужно сохранить файл скриншота в папке пользователя в Temp

Делаю следующее:

Определяю папку Temp

```
TCHAR myPath[MAX_PATH];
GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, myPath);
```

Добавочный путь

```
TCHAR t1Dir[MAX_PATH + 2] = { 0 };
```

Определяю имя пользователя

```
TCHAR UserName[MAX_PATH];
DWORD dwSize = sizeof(UserName);
GetUserName(UserName, &dwSize);
```

Соединяю все пути - В итоге получаю папку пользователя в папке Temp

```
auto DirPath = PathCombine(t1Dir, myPath, UserName); // auto тип typedef CHAR* LPSTR
```

Теперь пытаюсь сохранить скриншот файл в папке %Temp% в папке пользователя(Admin)

```
ScreenCapture(0, 0, sx, sy, "Screenshot.png",NULL); // по дефолту
```

Как мне соединить папку `DirPath`  и файл `"Screenshot.png"` ?

Comment: А еще раз PathCombine из t1Dir и "Screenshot.png" - не?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, пробовал, в итоге сохранялось в папке где лежит проект `auto Save = PathCombine(t1Dir,NULL, "Screenshot.png");`

Comment: А теперь почитайте MSDN про PathCombine и посмотрите что вы в нее передаете.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, :D Чёт не соображу Я

Comment: NULL у вас зачем во втором PathCombine, а?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, `PathCombine(путь к нужной мне папке, новая папка, имя файла);` Верно?  По сути мне нужно сделать так если я правильно понял PathCombine(DirPath,NULL,"имя файла.jpg" ); - DirPath (нужная мне папка пользователя в папке temp), 2-й аргумент по сути не нужен я его делаю NULL. Как должно быть правильно, может я реал что-то по глупому соображаю :(

Comment: Читайте MSDN внимательно, там даже написано для аргументов In, Out, InOut

Comment: Я имел в виду что второй аргумент NULL потому что я же через PatchCombine получил нужную мне папку temp и папку пользователя. Вот тут я стопорнулся)

Comment: Позвольте я просто процитирую документацию? "A pointer to a null-terminated string of maximum length MAX_PATH that contains the first path" это про второй параметр.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, Спасибо просёк фишку,`auto Save = PathCombine(t1Dir, DirPath,"Screenshot.png");`